# Windows 7 style calendar in Mootools or jQuery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, calendar, mootools

I am trying to build a Windows 7 (or even Windows Phone 7) style event calendar for a website (preferably using Mootools, native JS or else jQuery).

When we click on the month of Windows 7's clock, it shows the months of the entire year. Click it again and it shows the past dozen years and then group-by decade..

**Questions:**

1. What kind of transition/animation is used there?
2. Is there a ready-made Windows 7 style calender in JS?
3. In Windows Phone 7, the event calendar has same transition plus it shows a very small (almost unreadable) text in some date blocks, indicating there is some event on that date. Click on the date and it expands with details (like Outlook). Is it a good idea to deploy such control on branding website's events page? This is a SharePoint project. Any recommendations in this regard?

Comment: http://aryweb.nl/projects/mootools-datepicker/Test/ ? (you can easily extend it and add a w7 theme)

Comment: @stecb, thanks. Do you know what kind of transition effect they are using in windOS7 calender?

Comment: I don't have windows, therefore no I'm sorry :)